# xpath to return value from xml doc

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the following with one xpath expression:
I have an XML doc similar to this but with many 'results',

```
<result>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>joe</name>
</result>
<result>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>jim</name>
</result>
```

I'm passing a variable into a C# utility along with the xml, and want to return the name where the id = the variable.
I could loop through the xml until reach what I'm after but if there's a handy xpath way to do it I'm listening...
thanks

Comment: Well using LINQ to XML, the query is trivial... any reason you particularly want to use XPath?

Comment: Just that it's in a helper class for a Biztalk application and most of the other methods in the class are using xpath, other than that no reason, apart from possibly me wanting to practice xpath!  Thanks, I'll check out LINQ to XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a root element in there like "results" that XPath can validate, and that you don't have any other nodes named "result"...

```
//result[id=1]/name
```

Or you could get the text outright, instead of it being returned in a node

```
//result[id=1]/name/text()
```

And if you want to make sure that there's only one result, you could surround it with parens and put a [1] after

```
(//result[id=1]/name/text())[1]
```

I would also recommend testing with one of the xpath test sites out there like [this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), but beware that different xpath/xml parsers sometimes behave differently.